# Bootstrap creates too many backdrops

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to load pieces of HTML dynamically when certain events occur within the application. Some of these pieces of HTML may be modal dialogs. It should be fine, however when displayed, the modals create too many backdrops.

The following sample illustrate the problem (tested on Google Chrome).

```js
var html = '<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"> ' +
'  <div class="modal-dialog"> ' +
'    <div class="modal-content"> ' +
'      <div class="modal-header"> ' +
'        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button> ' +
'        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4> ' +
'      </div> ' +
'      <div class="modal-body"> ' +
'        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p> ' +
'      </div> ' +
'      <div class="modal-footer"> ' +
'        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> ' +
'        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> ' +
'      </div> ' +
'    </div><!-- /.modal-content --> ' +
'  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog --> ' +
'</div><!-- /.modal --> ';

var dlg = $(html).appendTo('body');

setTimeout(function () {
  
   dlg.modal({
     //backdrop: false,
     keyboard: false
   });
  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div>Hello</div>
```

Why does this happen, and how can this be fixed without requiring a "reusable" modal container?

Comment: ? Wow that's weird indeed. I have no idea what does this, but you can try to bypass it with a CSS hack, using `.modal-backdrop:last-child{ display : none }`

Comment: Yeah. The problem is that, sometimes, it creates 3, or even more backdrops. Weird indeed! :P

Comment: Try use $(".modal").modal({....instead of dlg.modal({...

Comment: @pecci Yes, for some reason, this works. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Now, can you explain why? :)

Comment: The best thing to do is check what the appendTo returns to the variable, use the console.log to check, i think it's not the actually element you have created.

Comment: @pecci perhaps. But I did check with `console.log` and it is the element. In Chrome, hovering over the console output representing the element, that element (i.e. the modal dialog node) is highlighted in Chrome. So, I assume it is the same, no?

Comment: @YanickRochon i dont think is the same, do this in the console and compare: console.log(dlg); console.log($(".modal"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $(".modal") instead of the dlg variable to call the modal.

```js
var html = '<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"> ' +
'  <div class="modal-dialog"> ' +
'    <div class="modal-content"> ' +
'      <div class="modal-header"> ' +
'        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button> ' +
'        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4> ' +
'      </div> ' +
'      <div class="modal-body"> ' +
'        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p> ' +
'      </div> ' +
'      <div class="modal-footer"> ' +
'        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> ' +
'        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> ' +
'      </div> ' +
'    </div><!-- /.modal-content --> ' +
'  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog --> ' +
'</div><!-- /.modal --> ';

$(html).appendTo('body');

setTimeout(function () {
  
   $(".modal").modal({
     //backdrop: false,
     keyboard: false
   });
  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: Note: if the DIV has an id, using the element ID works, too. So... I guess jQuery does not preserve the appended element?